# Как оценить износ SSD (Intel) по SMART данным?

Tags: железо, ssd, smart

На сервере SSD на 960 ГБ от Intel. Нагрузка на накопитель довольно приличная. Поэтому хотелось бы отслеживать состояние накопителя и заранее успеть заменить его, когда ему останется совсем мало...

На другом сервере ориентировался на S.M.A.R.T.-значения, параметр Wear_Leveling_Count, который уменьшается по мере износа со 100 до 0.

Здесь же такого параметра не наблюдаю. Вот, что показывает smartmontools:

```
~# smartctl -a /dev/sda3
Model Family:     Intel S4510/S4610/S4500/S4600 Series SSDs
Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2KB960G8
...
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
170 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unsafe_Shutdown_Count   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
175 Power_Loss_Cap_Test     0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       2587 (2 1093)
183 SATA_Downshift_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error_Count  0x0033   100   100   090    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Drive_Temperature       0x0022   072   072   000    Old_age   Always       -       28 (Min/Max 17/30)
192 Unsafe_Shutdown_Count   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
197 Pending_Sector_Count    0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
225 Host_Writes_32MiB       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10025
226 Workld_Media_Wear_Indic 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
227 Workld_Host_Reads_Perc  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       19
228 Workload_Minutes        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1092
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
234 Thermal_Throttle_Status 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0/0
235 Power_Loss_Cap_Test     0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       2587 (2 1093)
241 Host_Writes_32MiB       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10025
242 Host_Reads_32MiB        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2392
243 NAND_Writes_32MiB       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       11547
```

Вопрос: на какой (или на какие) параметры ориентироваться, чтобы понимать, примерно когда диску придет конец? Либо этих параметров для оценки недостаточно?

Возможно требуется какими-то другими средствами анализировать?

Comment: Media_Wearout_Indicator

Comment: Может Вам RAID поставить? Два диска зеркально работают. Когда один по факту накроется, Вы его замените по-горячему (или по-холодному) новым диском. И не надо отслеживать параметры, просто диски будут работать до фактического сбоя/отказа.

Comment: дороговато выходит. По ssh (Ubuntu) можно будет отследить, что один диск 
 в зеркальном RAID изношен? Вроде хостер говорил, что RAID программный будет.

Comment: SMART-данные для RAID показываются?

Comment: Но с другой стороны данные не критически важные, да и бэкапы сливаются с сервера раз в месяц.

Answer (score 4):

Морально устареет раньше. У нас давно и много, несколько сотен, серверных SSD intel под интенсивной нагрузкой в виде СУБД postgresql. От износа NAND не умер ни один. В общем-то, и вообще умерших припоминаю только один. Диски дорогие, но под интенсивную запись найти что-то лучше Intel сложно.

Тем не менее интерес представляют [параметры](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023512/memory-and-storage/data-center-ssds.html):

- F3h (243) - общий объём записи на NAND, счётчик тикает по 32мб. [S4510 должен выдержать](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/ru/ru/ark/products/134912/intel-ssd-d3-s4510-series-960gb-2-5in-sata-6gb-s-3d2-tlc.html) 3,4Пб, у вас сейчас 360Гб
- E9h (233) - Media Wearout Indicator. Только raw значение для него смотреть [бесполезно - 0 всегда](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106679), надо смотреть `normalized value`. В листинге smartmontools это столбец `value`
- E8h (232) - Available Reserved Space. Когда резерв кончается - значит основной массив NAND выходит из строя.

Ну и, как и для HDD, для SSD на показатели SMART полагаться так же не стоит. Может быть предупредит о проблеме, может быть и нет.